# How to convert model space to view space? (3d point to 2d point?)

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, 2d, point

I've been trying to get a cube to go on my screen. I just don't know how to make the verticies line up as screen positions (x,y). I have a cube OBJ. And I use the values that start with "v". I turn them into a list with the vertex positions. I just don't know how to make those vertex positions work and use a camera.

Any way to get to make a 3d point (x,y,z) into a 2d point?

Comment: Are you using OpenGL? If you are, there are plenty of libraries (such as GLM) that you can download and install to use matrix transformations. Some of them even provide projection and view matrices so you can render models on the screen (3D or 2D).

Comment: I'm trying to not use OpenGL libraries. And don't know how to replicate Matrix or Projection. I can only draw to the screen.

Comment: Well, if you want to know how to do it, go read a OpenGL tutorial about rendering things on the screen. LearnOpenGL is a good place to start. Sure, it uses the OpenGL API on C++, but the idea is the same, the scripting language doesn't matter here. You normally use a Projection Matrix, a View Matrix and a Model Matrix to transform the OBJ's vertices (x, y, z) and render them on the screen space.

Comment: It gets difficult to provide an example on how to do it, because you didn't provided any script. So there's no way to know which module you're using and if the answer is going to match what you need.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I don't know how to make matrices myself. I have seen alot of videos and articles talk about them, but I don't know how to transform the verticies on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pygame I did something like this recently.

Firstly you can make a Vector3D instance of the point. (Pygame makes this easy, otherwise good luck with the maths involved writing this yourself)

You need to center the scene on the camera, so first you take the points and subtract the camera position to find the relative positions.

RelativePos = <Px-Cx, Py-Cy, Pz-Cz>
This centers the scene. From here I HIGHLY suggest using Pygame's Vector math as it is as easy as a few lines of code.

Based on the camera's Angle relative to the scene, you can rotate the RelativePos of the point around the respective axes that define the camera direction. (For spherical coordinates, the order for axes of rotation are Z, Y, then X).

In Pygame you can do

```
Relativepoint.Rotate_z_ip(horizontal_angle)
Relativepoint.Rotate_y_ip(vertical_angle)
Relativepoint.Rotate_x_ip(rotation_angle) ## turns around the axis pointing into the screen, You might not need this last one
```

From here, your point will be rotated and moved relative to the looking direction and position of the camera.

Next, you can calculate the angle from the x axis (which points directly out infront of the camera) and from the y axis. BY then taking these angles and comparing them to some FOV, you can then offset (subtract) the calculated angles by the FOV/2 and then divide the angle values by the FOV of that axis.

What you get should be two numbers within 0 to 1. Any number outside will not be on the screen. 0 would be the bottom or left side of the screen while 1 would be the top or right sides. Just multiply the value by the screen px dimensions and BAM.

3d points projected on a 2d plane.

Comment: Wow that was very easy to understand. Do you have any math that could explain the Relativepoint.Rotate functions? I kind of don't understand this. The other stuff I understand more of.

Comment: The idea is that your camera is rotated arbitrarily in 3d space. you need to position your points relative to the direction the camera is pointing. SO you can define the angles of your camera (my method is an angle 0-360 deg from the x axis in the xy plane, an angle up from the xy plane at the vector of the first angle, and an angle that is the rotation around that vector). From these angles, you can rotate the point around each axis to "undo" the camera rotations. Once the points are rotated, your total reference frame will have your camera pointing down the x-axis and the points projected.

Comment: So the x and y axis calculation after should give me the positions where the points should be on the screen in 2d. Right?

Comment: After rotating, you will have the 3d position of the points relative to the camera and the x axis. using basic trig you can calculate the angles from the axis and compare the angles to the FOV to get values between 0 and 1 which you can then project to your screen